# Copying an XSLT variable

Tags: xml, xslt, variables, umbraco

I'm working on an Umbraco XSL Stylesheet and I am pretty stuck.

Basically, I have a parameter that I test and use it's value if it's present, otherwise I use the default parameter `$currentPage`.

**Here are the parameters**

```
<xsl:param name="source" select="/macro/sourceId" />
<xsl:param name="currentPage" />
```

**Here's the variable**

```
<xsl:variable name="current">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$source &gt; 0">
            <xsl:copy-of select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$currentPage" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

**And here's where I use it**

```
<xsl:for-each select="msxml:node-set($source)/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc and @level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
... code here ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

#### In a nutshell

**This works**

```
<xsl:variable name="source" select="$currentPage" />
```

**This doesn't**

```
<xsl:variable name="source">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$currentPage" /> <!-- Have tried using <xsl:value-of /> as well -->
</xsl:variable>
```

So how do you copy a variable without using the `select=""` attribute.

> **UPDATE:** I've tried using another approach (see below) but I get a *variable out of scope* exception.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$source &gt; 0">
        <xsl:variable name="current" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="current" select="$currentPage" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: XSLT1 or 2?  Where is $currentPage defined?  What is its type?

Comment: Hi @Jim, it's XSLT 1.0 (Umbraco) and $currentPage is a built in parameter that contains a node-set of the current page and it's children.

Comment: All I'm trying to do @Jim, is have a different value for `$source` based on a test.

Comment: can you explain what behavior you are seeing that does not match what you expect?  "This doesn't work" is not sufficient.

Comment: @Jim, what part of the question do you not understand? I have a parameter called $currentPage which contains a node-set. When I try to copy the parameter using `<xsl:variable name="source" select="$currentPage" />`, I get the expected output (the node-set). When I try and copy the parameter using `<xsl:copy-of />` or `<xsl:value-of />` within a `<xsl:parameter></xsl:parameter>`, I get text rather than the expected XML output.

Comment: Sorry for an error in my comment above `<xsl:parameter></xsl:parameter>` is actually `<xsl:variable></xsl:variable>`

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a one-liner XPath expression that you can use to define the variable. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Generally, this expression selects one of two nodesets, based on whether a given condition is `true()` or `false()`:**

```
$ns1[$cond] | $ns2[not($cond)]
```

**In your case this translates to**:

```
    umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source) 
|
    $currentPage[not(umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source))]
```

**The complete `<xsl:variable>` definition is**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select=
"        umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source) 
    |
        $currentPage[not(umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source))]
"/>
```

**This can be written in a more compact way**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vRealSource" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)"/>

<xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select=
    "$vRealSource| $currentPage[not($vRealSource)]"/>
```

Comment: Hmm I can't get that to work, it doesn't output anything. What exactly does not() do in this case? Does it check for an empty string or something else?

Comment: I changed not($vRealSource) to not($source) and it now works. Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you declare a variable in XSLT 1.0 without @select, but with some content template, the variable type will be of Result Tree Fragment. The variable holds the root node of this tree fragment.

So, with this:

```
<xsl:variable name="source"> 
  <xsl:copy-of select="$currentPage" />
</xsl:variable>
```

You are declaring `$source` as the root of a RTF containing the **copy** of the nodes (self and descendants) in `$currentPage` node set.

You can't use `/` step operator with RTF. That's why you are ussing `node-set` extension function.

**But**, when you say:

```
node-set($source)/ancestor-or-self::*
```

This will be evaluate to an empty node set, because a root node hasn't ancestors an it's not an element.

**EDIT**: If you have two node sets, and you want to declare a variable with the content of one of the two node sets depending on some condition, you could use:

```
<xsl:variable name="current" 
              select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)[$source > 0]
                      |$currentPage[0 >= $source]" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro, what would you suggest I do in this scenario? I'm basically attempting to have a different source based on a test. $currentPage works fine by itself and when using @select.

Comment: @Marko Ivanovski: See my edit for a solution. Do note that conditions should be mutal exclusive and take care about context (this two are context "free" because of variable reference).