# Alternative ways for setting variable value in XSLT?

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, variables, filter

I have a basic XSLT filter on a SharePoint 2007 DataFormWebPart:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[((ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@MyDate) ,1061 ,'MM'))=$MyParameter)]"/>
```

The *$MyParameter* comes from an ASP.NET control. But trying to set the variable value in any other ways results in an error:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows">
<xsl:value-of select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[((ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@MyDate) ,1061 ,'MM'))=$MyParameter)]"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows">
/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[((ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@MyDate) ,1061 ,'MM'))=$MyParameter)]
</xsl:variable>
```

The error I get is:  **Argument 1 must return a node-set. -->count($Rows)<--**

Ultimately, I am trying to achieve something similar:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="($MyParameter2 = '1')">
    <xsl:value-of select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[((ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@MyDate) ,1061 ,'MM'))=$MyParameter)]"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[((ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@MyDate) ,1061 ,'MM'))=$otherParameter)]"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Is anything like this possible with XSLT or should I look for other possibilities within SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834812/copying-an-xslt-variable

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it and see if already answers my question.

Comment: Try wrapping the `select` value with node-set(), if not use the answer on my question above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the **[`count()`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_count.html)** function, it counts the **nodes** in the **node-set** specified in the parameter.

The other two ways that you are trying to construct the `$Rows` variable are assigning **Strings**, not **node-sets**.

1. When you set the variable the first way, your `select` statement returns a **node-set** from the evaluated XPATH expression.
2. **`xsl:value-of` returns a string.**  So, when you create your variable the second way, you are assigning the *string value* of the node-set that was selected with your XPATH.
3. Placing string a string inside the `xsl:variable`, as you have done the third way, assigns that string value to the `$Rows` variable. Although that value *happens to be* an XPATH expression, it does not get evaluated as such.  It simply assigns the literal string "/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[((ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@MyDate) ,1061 ,'MM'))=$MyParameter)]" to the `$Rows` variable.

**Solution:** Try combining your XPATH criteria into a single `select` statement and incorporating the logic to test for the `$MyParameter2` value in the predicate filter:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" 
    select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[
        ((ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@MyDate) ,1061 ,'MM'))=$MyParameter) 
        and $MyParameter2='1'
      ] 
  | 
    /dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[
        ((ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@MyDate) ,1061 ,'MM'))=$otherParameter) 
        and $MyParameter2 !=1
       ]" 
 />
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. I think this time you could use `or` operator to reduce the expression.

Comment: @Indrek, you could probably improve the performance of this by creating a key, `<xsl:key name="rowsByDateTime" match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" use="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@MyDate) ,1061 ,'MM'))" />`; and then using that key: `select="key('rowsByDateTime', $MyParameter)[$MyParameter2 = '1'] | key('rowsByDateTime', $otherParameter)[$MyParameter2 !=1]`