# Parse XML to String in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I don't know how to pass an XML node to a javascript variable within XSLT. The input XML contains data for the application home screen, so it is dynamic. I need to pass an XML that will be the global model of the application.
I don't know if there is an easier way to do this with XSLT, but I'm trying to wrap XML into String and then associate it with an XMLModel, that doesn't seem right, but I don't know how to pass XML into an SAPUI5 control, inside the XSLT.
If anyone can help I appreciate it.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile Accessibility="false" CREATED_BY="Administrator"
    Country="US" PRINCIPAL_CREATION_DATE="0001387234199378"
    PRINCIPAL_MODIFY_DATE="0001564488020308" locale="en_US" uniquename="admin">
    <NavigationItems>
        <NavigationItem frame="" label="OEE"
            target="/XMII/CM/App/index.html" />
        <NavigationItem frame="" label="Admin" target="">
            <NavigationItem frame="" label="Administrator" target="">
                <NavigationItem frame="_blank" label="Promoção"
                    target="/XMII/CM/link1.html" />
                <NavigationItem frame="_blank" label="Label02"
                    target="/XMII/CM/link2.html" />
                <NavigationItem frame="_blank" label="Label03"
                    target="/XMII/CM/link3.html" />
                <NavigationItem frame="_blank" label="Label04"
                    target="/XMII/CM/link4.html" />
                <NavigationItem frame="_blank" label="Label05"
                    target="/XMII/CM/link5.html" />
            </NavigationItem>
        </NavigationItem>
    </NavigationItems>
</Profile>
```

XSL Transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" media-type="text/html" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:variable name="Profile">
        <xsl:value-of select="/Profile" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
            </head>
            <script>
                sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                sap.ui.require([
                "sap/m/Shell",
                "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer",
                "sap/ui/model/xml/XMLModel"
                ], function
                (Shell, ComponentContainer, XMLModel) {
                new Shell({
                app: new
                ComponentContainer({
                height : "100%",
                name : "App"
                }
                )}          
                ).placeAt("container");
                    var dataProfile = &quot;<xsl:value-of select="$Profile" />&quot;;

                var oModel = new XMLModel();
                oModel.setXML(dataProfile);
                sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"Profile");    
                });
                });
            </script>
            <body class="sapUiBody">
                <xsl:element name="div">
                    <xsl:attribute name="data-sap-ui-component">main</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="data-name">app</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="data-id">container</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="data-settings">'{"id": "app"}'</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

HTML out:

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<script>
                sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                sap.ui.require([
                "sap/m/Shell",
                "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer",
                "sap/ui/model/xml/XMLModel"
                ], function
                (Shell, ComponentContainer, XMLModel) {
                new Shell({
                app: new
                ComponentContainer({
                height : "100%",
                name : "App"
                }
                )}          
                ).placeAt("container");
                    var dataProfile = "












";

                var oModel = new XMLModel();
                oModel.setXML(dataProfile);
                sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"Profile");    
                });
                });
            </script>
<body class="sapUiBody">
<div data-sap-ui-component="main" data-name="app" data-id="container" data-settings="'{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;app&quot;}'"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>

<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "app": "./"
        }'
    data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
    data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" data-sap-ui-async="true">
</script>

<script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
            sap.ui.require([
                "sap/m/Shell",
                "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer",
                "sap/ui/model/xml/XMLModel"
            ], function (Shell, ComponentContainer, XMLModel) {
                new Shell({
                    app: new ComponentContainer({
                        height : "100%",
                        name : "App"
                    })
                }            
                ).placeAt("container");

                var dataProfile = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<Profile Accessibility=\"false\" CREATED_BY=\"Administrator\" " +
                    "Country=\"US\" PRINCIPAL_CREATION_DATE=\"0001387234199378\" " +
                    "PRINCIPAL_MODIFY_DATE=\"0001564488020308\" locale=\"en_US\" uniquename=\"admin\"> " +
                    "<NavigationItems> " +
                        "<NavigationItem frame=\"\" label=\"OEE\" " +
                            "target=\"/XMII/CM/App/index.html\" /> " +
                        "<NavigationItem frame=\"\" label=\"Admin\" target=\"\"> " +
                            "<NavigationItem frame=\"\" label=\"Administrator\" target=\"\"> " +
                                "<NavigationItem frame=\"_blank\" label=\"Promoção\" " +
                                    "target=\"/XMII/CM/link1.html\" /> " +
                                "<NavigationItem frame=\"_blank\" label=\"Label02\" " +
                                    "target=\"/XMII/CM/link2.html\" /> " +
                                "<NavigationItem frame=\"_blank\" label=\"Label03\" " +
                                    "target=\"/XMII/CM/link3.html\" /> " +
                                "<NavigationItem frame=\"_blank\" label=\"Label04\" " +
                                    "target=\"/XMII/CM/link4.html\" /> " +
                                "<NavigationItem frame=\"_blank\" label=\"Label05\" " +
                                    "target=\"/XMII/CM/link5.html\" /> " +
                            "</NavigationItem> " +
                        "</NavigationItem> " +
                    "</NavigationItems> " +
                "</Profile>";

                var oModel = new XMLModel();
                oModel.setXML(dataProfile);
                sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"Profile");

            }); 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody">
    <div data-sap-ui-component data-name="app"
        data-id="container" data-settings='{"id" : "mes"}'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Need help.
Thanks.

Comment: Cross-language communication between XSLT and Javascript is going to depend on your processing environment, which you haven't told us anything about. Are you running the XSLT within the browser? If so, which XSLT processor/browser combination?

Comment: I don't know which processor is used internally by the SAP NW AS 7.50, but engine conforms completely to the specifications given for XSLT 1.0.

Comment: The XSLT 1.0 specifications do not cover interaction between XSLT and Javascript: that part is completely processor-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your time Kay, I'm still thinking of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Javascript backtick string literals are supported you could try

```
var dataProfile = `<xsl:copy-of select="/"/>`;
```

as the closest attempt.

Comment: A great help, I can already see the XML, but I still need to replace the "with \" and also the special characters (ç for example).

Comment: @PabloSilva, in my view, if you know you target browsers that support the Javascript backtick string literal syntax (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) used in the example above then you don't need to escape any quotes in the XML. Only having a backtick in there would require escaping.

Comment: Got it now, great tip ... however, I still have the problem with special characters (ç, á, ã etc.). Do you know how to solve it easily?
Error: The following problem occurred: XML parse Error for  code: -1 reason: Entity 'ccedil' not defined src:...
Thanks

Comment: @PabloSilva, does the input you have shown in the sample contain any such characters? Do you get the error from the browser? Can you see whether it is given by the XSLT processing or later by the Javascript code? Do you get that error in a particular browser or in all of them?

Comment: Sorry, in the example code, I did not put the complete code, but yes, has several characters of the Brazilian language (pt_BR).

Comment: It's registered as "Promoção", but when you copy-of, the value is converted to "Promo&ccedil;&atilde;o". Error: The following problem occurred: XML parse Error for  code: -1 reason: Entity 'ccedil' not defined src (all browser). I edited the input xml.

Comment: @PabloSilva, I think this is a tough problem, assuming the input is well-formed XML without any entity references but simply with Unicode characters like `á` then I think the use of XSLT with `output method="html"` suggests to the XSLT processor that the serialization of such characters should be done when possible as entity references. So the whole approach of starting with XML to transform to HTML with Javascript strings to be parsed as XML again is causing that problem. Using `method="xml"` instead would avoid the entity problem but is of course not adequate for the text/html content type.

Comment: Thanks for your time Honnen, I'm still thinking of a solution.

Comment: I think the only option to use `output method="html"` but ensure the prevention of the use of entity references is to switch to an XSLT processor that has a proprietary extension for such stuff, for instance, Saxon 9, in the commercial editions only, offers an extension `saxon:character-representation="native;native"` http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html.

Comment: You helped a lot. However, there is no such possibility to use Saxon ... I am using an SAP NW AS (proprietary and closed application server). I will contact SAP support to review the options. AS, offers a service (http: // miidev: 565 / XMII / Illuminator? Service = SystemInfo & mode = CurrentProfile) that returns the data in XML, but would like to avoid this extra query (for performance reasons). Thanks again for your help … if support finds a solution, I update the post.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your `Profile` variable with `xsl:value-of` - and this is empty. Use `xsl:copy-of` instead (Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3835087/1305969)):

```
<xsl:variable name="Profile">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/Profile" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Then, if you can live a somewhat quick hack to avoid escaping the quotes of the XML string, replace the `&quot;` with `&apos;` in the `var dataProfile` making it

```
var dataProfile = &apos;<xsl:copy-of select="$Profile" />&apos;;
```

---

An **XSLT-3.0** solution is applying a replace on the [serialized](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-serialize) XML input:

```
var dataProfile = &apos;<xsl:value-of select="replace(serialize($Profile),'&quot;','\\&quot;')" />&apos;;
```

Then the quotes would be escaped properly and other UTF-8 chars would be passed through as well.

Comment: A great help, I can already see the XML, but I still need to replace the "with \" and also the special characters (ç for example)

Comment: I do not have this option, the application server (where is the XLS processor), can not be updated. Thanks